# why my progress bar from my activity doesn't show in my fragment after I press hardware back button?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

so I am using navigation controller component in Android. I have a progress bar in my `MainActivity` that will be used in all my fragments when the user need to wait while fetching data from server.

in my `onCreate` `MainActivity` it will be declared like this:

```
progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar_main_activity)
```

and in my `FragmentA`, it will be declared like this :

```
lateinit var mActivity : FragmentActivity
lateinit var progressBar : ProgressBar

override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
    super.onAttach(context)

    activity?.let { 
       mActivity = it 
    }

}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_user_control, container, false)
    progressBar = mActivity.progressBar_main_activity

    return fragmentView
}

 override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

    }
```

let say I have 2 fragments

I navigate from `FragmentA` to `FragmentB`. using the code below

```
val eventDetailDestination = UserControlFragmentDirections.actionGlobalDestinationEventDetail(selectedEvent)
Navigation.findNavController(fragmentView).navigate(eventDetailDestination)
```

in `FragmentB`, after the user do some actions in `FragmentB`, then they need to go back to `FragmentA`

here is the problem ....

if the user goes back from `FragmentB` to `FragmentA` using back button in the top left corner in action bar/toolbar, the progress bar in `FragmentA` will show up.

but if the user goes back using **hardware back button in the bottom right**, the progress bar in `FragmentA` will never show. even though I am sure `progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE` has been executed in `FragmentA` ?

I have tried to read the difference between back button in toolbar and hardware back button. but I have no Idea why this happened. please help :)

Comment: What do you exactly want? do you want progress bar with hardware back button or do you want to remove progress bar if user clicks on actoin bar back button?

Comment: why dont you show your progress bar in onResume of your fragment A?

Comment: @VinayJayaram I want my progress bar show up (in FragmentA) when user using hardware back button from FragmentB to FragmentA

Comment: @Sandeepdhiman Yes, I have moved the progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE to onResume but still it doesnt show

Comment: @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
   //show progressbar
    finish();
}

Comment: can you show your top left back button click code how you are going back from there? You might have called getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate() there;

Comment: @Sandeepdhiman I don't have any code for it, it is managed automatically. I am using Android Navigation component https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation

Answer (score 0):

That happens because fragmentA is getting deleted and recreated from scratch when using the hardware back button which is the expected result. You can override the default behaviour like below:

In MainActivity

```
override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
   //Use component backstack pop
   return Navigation.findNavController(fragmentView).navigateUp()
}
```

Sheding some more light

**Up vs. Back**

> The Up button is used to navigate within an app based on the
>   hierarchical relationships between screens. For instance, if screen A
>   displays a list of items, and selecting an item leads to screen B
>   (which presents that item in more detail), then screen B should offer
>   an Up button that returns to screen A.
>
> If a screen is the topmost one in an app (that is, the app's home), it
>   should not present an Up button.

..

> The system Back button is used to navigate, in reverse chronological
>   order, through the history of screens the user has recently worked
>   with. It is generally based on the temporal relationships between
>   screens, rather than the app's hierarchy.
>
> When the previously viewed screen is also the hierarchical parent of
>   the current screen, pressing the Back button has the same result as
>   pressing an Up button—this is a common occurrence. However, unlike the
>   Up button, which ensures the user remains within your app, the Back
>   button can return the user to the Home screen, or even to a different
>   app.

[image]

Reference:
[Android Navigation with Back and Up](http://www.androiddocs.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back)

Comment: Thank you very much, but, are you sure that code used in MainActivity ? what is the 'fragmentView' in Navigation.findNavController(fragmentView).navigateUp() ??? because I don't have fragmentView property in MainActivity.

Comment: That was a reference to your code: Should look like this => findNavController(R.id.my_nav_host_fragment).navigateUp()

Comment: I am sorry but type doesn't match, like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/klRJA.png

Comment: Try `findNavController(this@MainActivity, R.id.my_nav_host_fragment).navigateUp()` passing your activity as the first param

Comment: I am really sorry, but the progress bar still doesn't appear :(